# Solutions to N-queens when each queen is threathened by two queens.

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, chessboard

This is the problem of placing N chess queens on an N × N chessboard so that queens threaten each other sequentially. That is queen[x] threatens queen[x+1] for x = 0 to n-1, and queen[n] threatens queen[0]. So each queen is threatened by two and only two queens. Note the chain of threats is a hamiltonian cycle.

The difference with the classic version is that here each queen must be threatened by two queens and only two queens, and therefore each queen must threaten two queens and only two queens. Therefore this configuration must produce a hamiltonian cycle with N vertices and 2 * N edges.
As an example consider the following configuration of queens:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | 1 |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | 0 |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | 2 | 3 |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   | 4 | 5 |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   | 6 | 7 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The question is how to find all the solutions to this problem?

P.S. Queens can threaten through other queens. i.e. threats to a particular queen can not be obstructed by an intervening queen.

Comment: What do you mean by "sequentially"?

Comment: By sequentially I mean queen[x] threatens queen[x+1] for x = 0 to n-1, and queen[n] threatens queen[0]

Comment: You should clarify that in the question and make it more prominent. Except for this one word, both the title and the body of the question currently give the impression that the only condition is for each queen to threaten two other queens. This could also be achieved by more than one cycle of queens (although it seems plausible that a single cycle would yield the maximal number of queens).